# Proving differentiability with inequality

Tags: derivatives

Given: $0 \leq f(x) \leq x^2$ for all $x$.
Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $ x=0$, and find $f '(0)$. Give a counterexample of a function which satisfies the hypothesis, but which is not continuous for $x \neq 0$.

How can I prove the differentiability? I am not aware of any "squeeze" rules that could apply in this case. Also, I cannot come up with the counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

We have to show that

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f(h) - f(0)}{h} $$

exists. Notice

$$ 0 \leq \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} \leq \frac{ h^2 - f(0)}{h} = h $$

Since $f(0) = 0$ Why? $0 \leq f(0) \leq 0^2 $

Now, as $h \to 0$, we see that the quotient tends to $0$ by squeeze rule. In particular, it must be differentiable at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

$0 < |(f(x) - f(0))|/|(x - 0)| = |f(x)/x| < |x|$ . Take the limit as $x \to 0$ you get $f'(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example: $f(x) = x^2$ if $x$ is rational. $f(x) = -x^2$ if $x$ is irrational.

Show that this works by looking at the difference quotient, and proving that $f(x) = x$ if $x$ is rational, and $-x$ if $x$ is irrational is continuous at $0$ by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: $f(x)\ge 0$, make it $0$ at irrationals :)

Answer (score 0):

The derivative at $0$ of $f(x)$ is $Lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$. Now, you can bound $f(0)$ below by $0$, and $f(h)$ can be bounded above by $h^2$. This is un upper bound for $f'(x)$.